# Position Based statistics in DNA sequence

Tags: statistical-significance, biostatistics, bioinformatics

Let's say you have a DNA sequence with 21 positions, each of which can have one of four nucleotides (A,C,G,T).

For example, If I see lot of C's and G's (called 'GC content') at 19th position in all of my sequences (sample size = 1000 DNA seq.) , and I want to signify this GC content at 19th position compared to rest of the positions for all of my DNA sequences. Which statistical test is appropriate?

Comment: I think it might be useful to expand on what you mean by an appropriate test.  What sort of research question are you trying to answer?  Do you want to show that the 19th position has a higher GC content than the other 20 positions in a statistically significant way?  And more importantly, were you interested in the 19th position *a priori* or did you notice it was higher after collecting the data?

Comment: Yes, I want to show that the 19th position has a higher GC content than the other 20 positions in a statistically significant way. There is no a priori knowledge; it's just an observation after collecting data.

Comment: @Joshua: if you have any ideas or insights, it would be great. Thanks

Comment: Sadly, none I would offer as a canonical example for your situation, as genomics is outside of my expertise.  I do know you would need to control your false discovery rate, since you weren't looking for the 19th position *a priori*.  Perhaps others with a stronger genomics background will see the question.